# Powershell cannot write to registry key HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Real-Time Protection

Tags: windows-10, powershell, windows-defender

I would like to add a registry key using Powershell to set a group policy that disables OnAccessProtection in Windows Defender, with the following producing no error running as Admin, but doesn't do anything:

- ```powershell
  $registryPath = "HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Real-Time Protection"
  $Name = "DisableOnAccessProtection"
  $value = "1"

  if(!(Test-Path $registryPath)) {
    New-Item -Path $registryPath -Force | Out-Null
  }

  New-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name $name -Value $value -PropertyType DWORD -Force
  ```
- When I open the `RegEdit` to try to add the `DWORD`, I receive error:

  ```
  Cannot create value: Error writing to the registry
  ```

So even being an Administrator, I do not have access permissions here; how do I set the registry value anyway?

Comment: You would have to change the permissions on the key to give Administrator access to the key or elevate your process to that of System.

Comment: @Ramhound - on my system, Local Administrator has access. I assume OP is using a domain adminstrator then? Can you elevate a process to system with a GPO or do you mean using `psexec` or something similar?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers - A local Administrator does not have the permissions of System.

Comment: @Ramhound - I know but I don't see your point? On my system, either `Local Admin` or `System` can change that registry key.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers - The author should provide more information.  I checked the permissions of the key in question, Administrator only had read permissions, while System, WinDend, TrustIntstaler had write permissions.

Comment: Why is there a `:` after `HKLM` _(it's an invalid path)_? It also appears something isn't correct in the script, as running it without the `:` errors with: `Cannot use interface. The IDynamicPropertyCmdletProvider interface is not implemented by this provider.`

Answer (score 0):

**Obs.:** Tested on a clean installation of Windows 10 without any editing in the permissions of the relevant registry keys using only run as admin.

---

**1.** If Reg key do not exist you can create

**2.** After set value by `Type`instead`PropertyType`

**3.** You can also check if the key exists and the value is not `1`

**4.** If the key exists and the value is equal to `1`, your script has nothing to do!

```
$registryPath='HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Real-Time Protection'
$Name ="DisableOnAccessProtection"; $Value= '1'


if (!(Test-Path $registryPath)) { 
    
     New-Item -Path $registryPath -Force | Out-Null

     Set-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name $Name -Value $Value -Type DWORD -Force | Out-Null   
  
  } elseif ((Get-ItemProperty $registryPath).$Name -ne $Value) {
   
     Set-ItemProperty -Path $registryPath -Name $Name -Value $Value -Type DWORD -Force | Out-Null
 
 } else { 
 
   Write-Host nothing to do!
 
 }
```

Comment: This is not what OP asks. OP has a permission issue.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers Thanks for your comment, but with or without permission the code from User do not work

Comment: Ah, possible. That's for OP to clear up but this question being 3 days old, it seems OP has left the building ;)

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers So, I have not edit permission on pertinent key to test this

Comment: THanks for your comments, still here, yes I observed the typo in the script and will corerect it, but I have the issue also in regedit.exe, as I wrote.

Comment: @Erik Thanks for your comments, I’ll add SAP one suggest.

Comment: @Erik I test in 3 pc (one clean install) there no error, this is probably work for you, or some there some issue in your register, try test in another computer, also in different key in your pc